# TypeError: can not read property toString() of Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a login component on my Angular project and I want to save user id through localStorageService when a user logs in to the system.

My login component:

```
 login(){

    if(this.loginForm.valid){
      let loginModel = Object.assign({},this.loginForm.value)
      this.authService.login(loginModel).subscribe(response=>{
        this.toastrService.success(response.message)
        this.getUser(loginModel.email);
        this.localStorageService.addToken(response.data)
        this.router.navigate([""])
      },responseError=>{
        console.log(responseError)
        this.toastrService.error(responseError.error)
      })
    }
  }
```

and LocalStorageService:

```
 addCurrentUserId(user:User){
    localStorage.setItem("currentUserId",user.id.toString());
  }
```

When a user logs in to the system and I click F12, this error appears:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at LocalStorageServiceService.addCurrentUserId (local-storage-service.service.ts:43)
```

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory that `user.id` is undefined check what data you are getting inside user. If using mongoDb there is a high chance that it will be `user._id` instead of `user.id`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 2):

Some errors or often very explicit! :p

In your case, the answer to your problem is just below your nose :
`Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`
`local-storage-service.service.ts:43`

You are calling `user.id.toString()` on line 43 of your code and the error is telling you that the code you are executing is trying to call `.toString()` on ... well ... something undefined, and that something is your `user.id`!
Something else might be happening in your code before that `.toString()` call that you do not want to happen.

In any case, you could also check if the user id is defined by simply using an if statement, or even better, you could use what is called [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html). This would mean your code would look like this : `user.id?.toString()`. If the user id isn't defined (`undefined`), then `.toString()` will not be called and the `undefined` value will be used in your `setItem(...)` call.

Also, do you really need to call `.toString()` ?